# React Firebase Semantic Responsive Navigation not Displaying Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, semantic-ui

I built a barebones firebase auth app with react and Im trying to integrate semantic-ui's [responsive navigation menu](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/docs/app/Layouts/HomepageLayout.js).

My responsive menu works however the problem Im having is that my routes are not displaying on the page. I think the problem I may be having is either my props or children are not being passed down to my App.js file from my ResponsiveNavContainer component. My `<MobileNav/>` and `<DesktopNav/>` components include my `<Navigation />`  component.

Im not receiving any errors. Can someone point me in the right direction?

**App.js**

```
...
...

const App = () =>
  <div>
    <Router>
          <ResponsiveNavContainer>
            <div>
              <Route exact path={routes.LANDING} component={() => <LandingPage/> }/>
              <Route path={routes.HOME} component={() => <HomePage/>}/>
              <Route path={routes.SIGN_IN} component={() => <SignInPage/>} />
              <Route path={routes.SIGN_UP} component={() => <SignUpPage />} />
              <Route path={routes.ACCOUNT} component={() => <AccountPage />} />
              <Route path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={() => <PasswordForgetPage />} />
            </div>
          </ResponsiveNavContainer>
      </Router>
  </div>
```

**Navigation.js**

```
...
...

const ResponsiveNavContainer = (props, { children, authUser }) => 
    <div>
        <MobileNav>{children}</MobileNav>
        <DesktopNav>{children}</DesktopNav>
    </div>

ResponsiveNavContainer.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node
}


const Navigation = (props, { authUser }) => 

    <div>
        { authUser ? <NavigationAuth /> : <NavigationNonAuth /> } 
    </div>


const NavigationAuth = () =>

    <ul>
        <li><Link to={routes.LANDING}>Landing Page</Link></li>
        <li><Link to={routes.HOME}>Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to={routes.ACCOUNT}>Account</Link></li>
        <li><SignOutButton/></li>
    </ul>


const NavigationNonAuth = () =>

    <ul>
        <li><Link to={routes.LANDING}>Landing Page</Link></li>
        <li><Link to={routes.SIGN_IN}>Sign In</Link></li>
        <li><Link to={routes.SIGN_UP}>Sign Up</Link></li>
    </ul>


Navigation.contextTypes = {
    authUser:PropTypes.object
}


export default ResponsiveNavContainer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was correct. I needed to pass down the children via props using `props.children`

```
const ResponsiveNavContainer = (props, { authUser }) => 
    <div>
        <MobileNav>{props.children}</MobileNav>
        <DesktopNav>{props.children}</DesktopNav>
    </div>
```